# Auto refresh dropdown after send new value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have a dropdown with this code:

and other block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*Primo pulsante attributo*/

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#bloccoetapulsante').click(function() {

            var dati = $("#campo").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "database/bloccoattributi.php",
                data: 'dati=' + dati,
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "HTML",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Attributo inserito");

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="campo" id="campo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci altro">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="bloccoetapulsante"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
```

How can i update dropdown, without reload page, after add a new value with button (bloccoetapulsante)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#id").html("Attributo inserito"); // #id as a dropdown Id
}
```

or

```
$("#id").append("Attributo inserito");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');` after ajax call. it will refresh `Bootstrap selectbox`